# sonar c# rules removed from quality profile after upgrade 4.5.6 to 5.6

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I've recently upgraded my testing environment from 4.5.6 with c# 3.3 to 5.6 with c# 5.3.2
I noticed that in the upgrade process some of sonar's c# rules have been omitted (e.g. "Assignment should not be used inside sub-expressions"), it seems that the fxcop rules and the common rules have migrated correctly.

I also noticed that the rule id have possibly changed. on 4.5.6 c# 3.3 the rule id is csharpsquid:AssignmentInsideSubExpression, and on 5.6 c# 5.3.2 the id is csharpsquid:S1121
.
Could this be the reason?
If so, why was the id changed?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's exactly the reason. C# plugin 3.3 is quite old. For maybe two years, we have dropped these legacy IDs, and all the rules use the Sxxx format.